# Is PMKID same for a specific client when it is roaming from AP1 to AP2 using WPA2-Enterprise?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, ieee-802.1x

I have two access points (APs) setup with the same SSID name and using the same freeRADIUS server for station authentication. I have read Cisco documentation about fast roaming. So I have this doubt in my mind. Is PMKID same for a specific client when it is roaming from AP1 to AP2 using WPA2-Enterprise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

PMKID is an unique value as a result of hash function combines the PMK with Access Point's MAC address and Client's MAC address.

Comment: Isn't it the combination of `authenticator's address (aa)` and `supplicant's address (spa)` as per hostapd documentation? And here authenticator is RADIUS server. In this case, PMKID supposed to be the same right?

Comment: @NayabBashaSayed These terms mean: Authenticator = AP, Supplicant = Client and Authentication Server = Radius. You can check again the docs from hostapd (https://w1.fi/hostapd/) and from CWNP (https://www.cwnp.com/uploads/802-11i_key_management.pdf)